# NuGet on Ubuntu: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'VSS.NuGet.Authentication

Tags: authentication, npm, azure-devops, token, vsts-npm-auth

I'm trying to use [Azure DevOps (formerly VSTS) Auth helper for npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vsts-npm-auth) and since I'm on Ubuntu I'm following the steps showed in the "Other" tab of [Project setup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/npm/npmrc?view=azure-devops&tabs=other%2Cclassic#project-setup) guide.

After I accomplish the 5 steps I go in the home and I run the following command:

`vsts-npm-auth -config .npmrc`

But I get the following error:

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'VSS.NuGet.Authentication, Version=0.42.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=<my-token>' or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'VSS.NuGet.Authentication, Version=0.42.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=<my-token>'
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'VSS.NuGet.Authentication, Version=0.42.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=<my-token>' or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'VSS.NuGet.Authentication, Version=0.42.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=<my-token>'
```

I tried to reset `vsts-npm-auth` as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/npm/npmrc?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows%2Cclassic#reset-vsts-npm-auth) or install the latest version (`vsts-npm-auth@0.43.0`), but both didn't fix the issue.

Could be some kind of bug related to Ubuntu? I'm currently on version 22.04.3 LTS.

How could I solve this "missing file" error? **VSS.NuGet.Authentication** seems to be a file of the source of `vsts-npm-auth package`... I would like to open an issue on their repository, but seems they don't have it :(

Comment: Same issue occurred on my Ubuntu version 20.04.4 LTS.

Comment: Come here, hug me

Answer (score 0):

An attempt to run npm install against Azure Artifacts has landed me on this page as I was trying to connect to an npm feed.

System: Linux Mint 21 Cinnamon

In the "Artifacts" => "Connect to feed" => npm section in Azure Devops there's a new set of instructions which basically guides you through creating an .npmrc manually, however, I can't find this guide outside the devops environment and the guide is generated to cater to your specific organization, so copying it over here would not be particularly useful. So just go over here:

[image]

Open the "Other" tab and follow instructions. It'll skip the vsts-npm-auth tool entirely.

For reference, here's the guide with professionally blacked out sensitive information:
[image]
But I can't imagine having access to the org user name, path to the artifact feed and ability to generate an access token without also being able to access the "Connect to feed" page.